# Subsetting by counts

Tags: r, count, dplyr, subset

I have a data.frame

```
library(dplyr)

ID <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5)
Score <- c(20,22,34,56,78,98,56,43,45,33,24,54,22)
Quarter <- c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q1","Q2","Q1")
df <- data.frame(ID,Score,Quarter)
```

I only want to deal with the data that has all 4 quarters (Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 in column "Quarters"). One way I thought I could do this is subset when the ID is present 4 times because it is repeated in each Quarter. I am having a hard time sub-setting on the count of IDs. I tried:

```
filter(df, count(df, vars = ID)==4)
```

But it did not work and guidance would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way we can do is by using `n_distinct` to get unique values for each `ID` and filter the group which has all 4 values.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(n_distinct(Quarter) == 4)


#    ID Score Quarter
#  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>  
#1  1.00  20.0 Q1     
#2  1.00  22.0 Q2     
#3  1.00  34.0 Q3     
#4  1.00  56.0 Q4     
#5  3.00  56.0 Q1     
#6  3.00  43.0 Q2     
#7  3.00  45.0 Q3     
#8  3.00  33.0 Q4
```

---

Equivalent base R implementation using `ave` would be

```
df[as.numeric(ave(df$Quarter, df$ID, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))) == 4, ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few alternatives.  The last three are base solutions.

#1 is an SQL solution which creates a one-column data frame `df0` with only those IDs having 4 quarters which is then joined to `df` thereby eliminating all other IDs.

#2 is a dplyr solution which filters the groups retaining only those with 4 rows.

#3 is a data.table solution which returns the rows for those ID groups having 4 rows and NULL for the other groups.  This has the effect of eliminating the other groups.

#4 is a zoo solution which converts `df` to a wide form zoo object with quarters along the top and ID as the time index. It then removes any row having an NA and reshapes back to the original using `fortify.zoo` also reordering back to a sorted order. The last line of the solution could be omitted if the row order does not matter. Interestingly it does not use knowledge of the number 4.

#5 is a base solution which splits `df` into a list of data frames, one per ID, and then uses `Filter` to extract those having 4 rows.  Finally it puts it all back together.

#6 is a base solution which creates a vector having one element per row of `df` containing the number of rows (including the current row) having the ID in that row.  Then use `subset` to reduce `df` to those rows for which that vector equals 4.

#7 is a base solution which splits `df` into a list of data frames, one per ID, and then uses `Reduce` to iterate over it appending the current data frame to what we have so far if it has 4 rows or just keeping what we have so far if not.

```
# 1
library(sqldf)
sqldf("with df0 as (
  select ID from df group by ID having count(*) = 4
)
select * from df join df0 using (ID)")

# 2
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(n() == 4) %>% ungroup

# 3 
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[, if (nrow(.SD) == 4) .SD, by = ID]

# 4
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(df, split = "Quarter")
df2 <- fortify.zoo(na.omit(z), melt = TRUE, names = names(df)[c(1, 3:2)])
df2 <- df2[order(df2$ID, df2$Quarter), ]

# 5
do.call("rbind", Filter(function(x) nrow(x) == 4, split(df, df$ID)))

# 6
subset(df, ave(ID, ID, FUN = length) == 4)

# 7
Reduce(function(x, y) if (nrow(y) == 4) rbind(x, y) else x, split(df, df$ID))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `base R` method using `table`, `rowSums` and `%in%`.  We get the frequency count of 'ID', 'Quarter' columns with `table`, convert it to logical `matrix` where 0 values are TRUE and all others FALSE (`!table(...)`), get the rowwise sum (`rowSums`), convert to logical `vector`, get the `names` of the elements that are TRUE and create a comparison with the ID using `%in%` to `subset` the dataset

```
subset(df, ID %in% names(which(!rowSums(!table(df[c(1,3)])))))
#   ID Score Quarter
#1   1    20      Q1
#2   1    22      Q2
#3   1    34      Q3
#4   1    56      Q4
#7   3    56      Q1
#8   3    43      Q2
#9   3    45      Q3
#10  3    33      Q4
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out I can do this as well:

```
df[df$ID %in% names(table(df$ID))[table(df$ID)==4],]
```

It gets the desired result with using only the counts from ID